# MagicaVoxel Matter properties not showing in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, webvr, magicavoxel

I am using MagicaVoxel to build my scene, exporting via `File > Export > obj` and importing via

```
<a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="sceneObj" src="assets/scene.obj"></a-asset-item>
    <a-asset-item id="sceneMtl" src="assets/scene.mtl"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
<a-entity obj-model="obj: #sceneObj; mtl: #sceneMtl"></a-entity>
```

I can change the material of portions of the scene via MagicaVoxel's "Matter" tools in the Render view, but properties like transparency do not transfer to the scene in A-Frame. Neither can I set `transparency="true" opacity="0.5"` on an entire model and see my desired results.

For now I have settled on using A-Frame primitives to create the portions of my scene that require transparency, but if it is possible to create more elements via MagicaVoxel I would prefer that for stylistic consistency and ease of workflow. Is this not possible or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT1:
Here's the version where I'm setting transparency:
 - [Code](https://github.com/beccannlittle/beccannlittle.github.io/blob/ef08a2dea437ce8b3db12b576baf9a2872f2893b/index.html)
 - [Running application](https://beccannlittle.github.io/)

EDIT2: 
Removed `aframe-extras`.

Comment: Hi Becca, do you have a glitch with an example of your code so we can see what is going on? Also, what is aframe-extras for?

Comment: @mo-kargas the [Building with MagicaVoxel](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/guides/building-with-magicavoxel.html#obj) guide in the A-Frame documentation explicitly states to use it in the .PLY section:
> To see the .PLY model in A-Frame, use the ply-model component found in Don McCurdy’s aframe-extras.
The example in the .OBJ section still uses aframe-extras, so I guess I just assumed I needed it there too.

Comment: I see. If you're on 0.5.0, obj-model is actually part of the core library (https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/obj-model.html). In aframe-extras it is "object-model" (subtle component name difference) or "ply-model" for PLY's

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I'll get rid of it, since I am no longer baking shadows and using PLYs due to their greater load time.

Answer (score 0):

The Render section of MagicaVoxel is not real-time. Pre-rendered screenshots can not be run in real-time. Notice how long it takes to render each frame on each setting or camera angle you change.

Comment: I'd still like to create something in MagicaVoxel and use A-Frame's `transparent` and `opacity` properties to change the material. I am unable to do this.

Comment: Try `material="transparent: true; opacity: 0.5"`

Comment: I don't think MagicaVoxel provides any way to export a file while including transparency, emissives, etc. You could create something in MagicaVoxel and then change the materials in another program, but that information isn't included when you export straight from MagicaVoxel.

Comment: I was hoping that material properties would be exported to the MTL, but I'm thinking @ngokevin is right and the "Matter" options are part of render and not saved like I was hoping. In the meantime I can confirm that neither `transparent="true" opacity="0.5"` nor `material="transparent:true;opacity:0.5"` result in a transparent model from MagicaVoxel (working fine on A-Frame primitives)